# that still leaves a boy who paid me to come here -- I don't understand what that means -- from the movie "Ironclad 2: Battle for Blood"

Tags: meaning

> - You know you're free to go. If there's a debt, it's been paid.
> - Not yet. **That still leaves a boy who paid me to come here**.
> - What's a hired man without his word?
> - A man who ain't hired no more. A long ride through France taught us that. That's all we are, brother. Swords for hire. Willing to shed a cup of blood now and then. Well, that's me. What's keeping you here?
> - Like you said, what's a hired man who doesn't stick to his word?
> - You sure there wouldn't be a lord's daughter keeping it too?

I don't understand that sentence.

Comment: This is about *interpretation of character motivation in a narrative context*, not the meaning of the words as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not enough context here to answer. My guess, based on what I know of the plot, is that Hubert has paid Guy (who says the line you've asked about), his cousin, to come home and help protect Hubert's land/castle. Guy does but Hubert is killed. Guy's fellow mercenary is telling him that Guy's earned his money and could leave.

Guy still feels that he owes more to Hubert even though Hubert is dead.

In other words, Guy came home mainly because he was paid, but now feels some positive emotions towards him cousin and his homeland.